# Info Window URL needs to be prefixed with http NOT the default https

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I am using the following code in the fusion tables 'customize info window' to create hyperlinked URL's from a column in my table:

"{URL}"

This works fine in returning the clickable hyperlink in the info box except fusion maps by default tacks on https: instead of http: when the link is clicked. This causes problems when the user clicks the hyperlink and it tries to take them to a secure site when in fact it is not secure. The browsers throw up all sorts of warnings that will scare the pants off a lot of users who don't know what is happening.

Does anybody know how to remedy this and have the default be http and not the current https?

Thanks, Shep

Answer (score 0):

You may want to abandon the "{URL}" approach and display the hyperlink with some simple HTML.  [This example from Google](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/change_infowindow_content) shows how to modify the info window's HTML in Javascript:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(layer, 'click', function(e) {

      // Change the content of the InfoWindow
      e.infoWindowHtml = e.row['Store Name'].value + "<br>";

      // If the delivery == yes, add content to the window
      if (e.row['delivery'].value == 'yes') {
        e.infoWindowHtml += "Delivers!";
      }
    });
```

Changing the `e.row['Store Name']` to your URL column name (maybe, `e.row['URL']`) and surrounding by a couple of hyperlink tags `<a>` should do the trick:

```
e.infoWindowHtml = "<a href='" + e.row['URL'].value + "'>Click here!</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways:

1. Specify a full URL including protocol in your data
2. Use <a href="http://{URL}">Link here</a> in a custom info window layout
3. Completely override the content as in the answer above

I would recommend #1 because you can choose the right protocol for every link. However #2 is probably easier in that you can leave your data the way it is.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you @eltiar for that override and Rod for your options. I am using #2 for now but will use the above code for mixed protocols.